# Why is my code giving a value error that the list index is out of range?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, valueerror

```
inp_list=[10,1,11,1,29,876,768,10,11,1,92,29,876]

for i in range(len(inp_list)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(inp_list)):
        if (inp_list[i]==inp_list[j]):
            inp_list.remove(inp_list[i])
            
print(inp_list)
```

In the code, I was trying to remove the duplicate elements in the list. It is giving me a ValueError for line `if (inp_list[i]==inp_list[j):`, I am not able to understand why is it showing me an error.

I tried looping through the elements of the list using its index numbers in the first for loop. In the second for loop, I was trying to loop through the elements with index numbers index+1, but I limited the end value of the range within the the length of the list. Still, I am getting a ValueError, saying that the list index is out of range.

I expected the output to be like this:
[10,1,11,29,876,768,92]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your ```for j in range(i + 1, len(inp_list)):``` is going to give you trouble as when ```i``` becomes ```len(inp_list) - 1```,  ```i+1``` is going to be out of bounds when applied to ```inp_list```.

Comment: @ewokx - I wondered about that, but `range(i + 1, len(inp_list))` produces an empty range when `i + 1` is greater than `len(inp_list)`, so that's not an issue.

Comment: ```range(i + 1, len(inp_list))``` isn't a problem but referring to ```inp_list[i + 1]``` is the problem.

Comment: I used the same logic of using two **for loops** with a +1 index, for solving similar problems for list datatype, and it had worked earlier for me. For only this problem, it is giving me an error.

Comment: @ewokx - The code doesn't try to do that (because, again, it gets an empty range). The problem is making the list shorter but continuing to use the old range of indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're *removing* elements from `inp_list`, which means it gets shorter, but the ranges you're looping through still have the indexes for the old size of the list. So you end up going past the end of the now-shorter list.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I got it now, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Converting to a set would remove all the duplicates.

```
output_list = list(set(inp_list))
```

If you want to keep the same order

```
from collections import OrderedDict 

output_list = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(inp_list))
```

See the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists).